# Define the reference type

Tags: c#

I use a singleton for my project.
It is seen not to be used like below, because it's local variable:

```
var index = undomanager.singleton.index;
index--;
```

so how can I define it in reference type in C#?
or I have to use

```
undomanager.singleton.index--;
```

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a Good Question*](/help/how-to-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad. Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: It can't be used like that because it's obviously a value type (eg an int), not because it's a local variable. The variable stores a copy of that property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing `var index`, declares a *new variable*. This variable presumably is an `int`, which is a *value type*, and so when you assign to it via  `= undomanager.singleton.index;` what you have actually done is *make a copy* of the property value in your singleton. The operation on the next line therefore only applies to the copy.

On the other hand, writing `undomanager.singleton.index--;` — with no additional variable — updates the property value directly. There is no copy.

If you *really* want a local variable, you can do it like this:

```
var s = undomanager.singleton;
s.index--;
```

The above code creates a new variable `s`, but then assigns a *reference* (not a copied value, because your singleton is almost certainly not a value type) for the full singleton object. Now you can update the `index` property on this object and see the expected results.